# Не добавляются записи

Tags: sql-server, sql

Создал приложение и проверил работу его в MS SQL 2008. Передал Заказчику, а у него MS SQL 2000. Не работает добавление записей. В таблицах поля все обычные bigint, int, char, decimal, datetime. Кто подскажет, в чем дело?

Comment: все Ванги в отпуске, может немного конкретики добавите ?

Comment: Нак именно производится добавление записей? Не стесняйтесь, покажите нам немного кода.

Answer (score 1):

Версия 2000 не поддерживает добавление нескольких записей одним оператором через конструктор таблицы ([VALUES](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_operator_insert.html)). Если не в этом дело, то хотелось бы увидеть код и текст ошибки.